# Create a variable with variable name containing a value from another variable

Tags: java

So, for a while loop, I am creating a variable each time it goes through, assigning "i" as a counter to count the amount of times looped. I wish to append this to the end of a variable, and it occurred to me that I could probably use an object for this, but it's the same issue, and that would just make the problem more complicated. Code as follows.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 * Counts composition of children's sexes among nuclear families.
 *
 * @author Thomas Morey
 * @version 10/7/18
 */
public class Family
{
    public static void main() throws IOException{
        File read = new File("C:/Users/tdmor/Desktop/Misc/School/AP Comp Science/Recources/maleFemaleInFamily.txt"); //entire file path necisary?
        Scanner inf = new Scanner(read); //stands for in file
        String family;
        int quan;
        int i = 1;
            while(inf.hasNext()){
                family = inf.next();
                String famNum/*increment here*/ = family; //create a variable with the int "i" appended to the end of the variable name to represent how many families there are.
                quan = i;
                System.out.println(family);
                i++;
            }
    }
}
```

So upon further thought I should probably explain what the desired result of the program is. It sorts the amount of families with two children into categories based on their children's sex. for instance, BB would be two boys, GG two girls, whilst having BG and GB be different things. This will output the total amount of families as well as the amount in each family with a percentile.

Comment: Use an array or list structure instead.

Comment: actually you just defined what an array is for.

Comment: There is no dynamic variable in Java. What are you trying to achieve with that variable?

Comment: Vivek I'm creating a new variable for while the list in the text file continues.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `List` here:

```
List<String> famNum=new ArrayList();
while(inf.hasNext()){
    family = inf.next();
    famNum.add(family);
    quan = i;
    System.out.println(family);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Then you do not need quan you only have to take list.size()

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of appending the variable for the counter to the end of the family variable:

```
FileReader read = new FileReader("PATH");
Scanner inf = new Scanner(read); //stands for in file
String family;
int quan;
int i = 1;
    while(inf.hasNext()){
          family = inf.next();
          String famNum = family + " " + i; //create a variable with the int "i" appended to the end of the variable name to represent how many families there are.
          quan = i;
          System.out.println(famNum);
          i++;
        }
```

And here is your output:

```
johnsons 1
flintstons 2
harrolds 3
smiths 4
cambells 5
```

However, there's no need to create a new object. You can truly append as follows:

```
family += " " + i;
```

Simply use the += operator + i.

Comment: I wonder if he is trying to express he wants to use the value later on (besides printing); in that case an array might be what he wants to go after

Comment: I don't want the value to be printed along side the string, I wanted it to be part of the name referenced in the code, so it creates a new variable each time it loops with a different name changing the number at the end(i) by one